# Driving stepper to follow sequential positions

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper, stepper-motor

I was exploring the stepper motor library AccelStepper and using it because of it's easy interface to control multiple stepper motors simultaneously. Recently I got a problem. I needed a stepper motor to follow position commands of the following kind :

```
int steps[] = { -0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4,
                4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, -0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, 
                -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13,  
                6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3,
                3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, -0 };
```

This array is truncated in the middle. Actual command is continous throughout the first position to last position.These are the absolute steps that the motor needs to turn.

I generated the pulses to achieve this as following:

```
void loop() {
  delay(5000);

  int stepperDelay = 9000;

  for (int i = 0; i < 701; i++) {
    int moveTo = steps[i + 1] - steps[i];
    if (moveTo < 0) {
      digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < abs(moveTo); x++) {
      digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(stepperDelay);
      digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(stepperDelay);
    }
  }

}
```

Writing the pulses myself gave me a satisfactory result in transition from one abs position to another abs position. The overall working was smooth to the extent I desired.
**But, it's gonna take me a lot more effort to apply this to three different stepper motors simultaneously, so I tried to use AccelStepper to do the same thing. I tested the following code :**

```
void setup() {
  st1.setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
  st1.setAcceleration(acc);
  st1.setCurrentPosition(0);
}
void loop() {
  delay(5000);

  for (int i = 0; i < 703; i++) {
    st1.moveTo(m1_steps[i]);
    while (st1.distanceToGo() != 0 ) {
      st1.run();
    }
  }

}
```

This code when I tested, made the motor to follow the same trajectory, but it failed to make it smooth. The movement is not smooth, appears to have some pause betweeen every step.
has anyone any clue what might be the appropriate way ?

**I tested with both A4988 driver and TB6600, same issue.**

Comment: Pause between steps is what a stepper motor does.  That's how it works.  If you want a shorter pause so it looks smoother then increase the speed.

Comment: for the A4988,  the STEP input does not have to be a square wave ... the motor moves on low/high transition only ... the input has to stay high for only 1 microsecond

Comment: @Delta_G Thanks for the reply !! I am not actually complaining about the pause between the steps, it's actually between two positions in the array. For some reasons library method seems to implement it more coarser at any speed for that matter. I ended up implementing a non-blocking for loop to simultaneously actuating three motors. I would love to hear your thoughts on that. 
```

```

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the insight. I will try that to save extra microseconds.

Comment: Is it just that accelstepper is slowing down at the end of one and speeding up at the start of the next?

Comment: @Delta_G yes, something like that. Perhaps it's because of the run() method which tries to optimize the movement of due steps, but in my case since the due steps changes in a loop as it has to go through the positions given in the array resulting in lack of continuity. I tried to search how the 3D printers are coded since they have to loop through the gcode as well but didn't find useful information.

Comment: If you don't want acceleration and deceleration between steps, then pick a different stepper library.  AccelStepper is specifically written to add that acceleration and deceleration.  Try the normal Arduino Stepper library instead.